# I need to fill text field programatically in a web page opened inside a WebView. How To?

Tags: java, android

I have created a WebView and opened up a web page in it that contains a form. I need to fill that form programmatically (need to get some data form sqlite database and fill it).

how i can do that ? can anyone please help me out.

EDIT : the web page is a sign-up form and i do not own that web page.. i cannot add java script into that page.

Comment: hey did you solved your problem . can you please refer to any code example , please .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use javascript in this situation.

Here is how. Make your webview javascript-enabled.

Java code in your webview activity

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript: fillUpForm(inputId,inputValue)");
```

javascript in your html file

```
function fillUpForm(id,value)
{
  document.findElementById(id).value=value;
}
```

Frankly, I am no expert in javascript. But this should give you starting point.

---

Well, in your case,

I would try this

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('trop').value='some value';})()");
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. the problem is that i do not own the web page. so i cannot write the function and stuff in the web page. the web page is the simple sign up form.

          String alertDialogString = "javascript:document.getelementById(\"trop\").value =\"some value\"";
          view.loadUrl(alertDialogString); 

thats what i am doing. but its not working

Comment: Its not working for me. I am opening google.com in my web view & then adding this javascript but it just displays the empty page.   browser = new WebView();
                webEngine = browser.getEngine();
                webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
                webEngine.load("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('q').value='some value';})()");

Comment: hey . can you please refer to any full example. I have not worked with this kind of code before .