# insert text into a text field in webview programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-webview

i have a web view in which i want to insert some text(like the autofill feature). Is there any way to do it? I tried using java script.

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false,text );
```

But it didn't worked.

Comment: Hope it is work:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222495/i-need-to-fill-text-field-programatically-in-a-web-page-opened-inside-a-webview

Answer (score 1):

you need use javascript interface mechanism given by android.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("javascript://your_javascrpit_method");
```